# Рисование на виджете вне функции paintEvent ()

Tags: c++, qt

Возможно ли рисовать на виджете при помощи **QPainter** вне функции **paintEvent ()**? 
В документации написано, что из всех стандартных бэкэндов,  **QWidget** единственный, на котором можно рисовать только внутри **paintEvent()**.

Но так же там сказано, что можно создать собственный бэкэнд, унаследовавшись от **QPaintDevice** и переопределив **paintEngine()**.Непонятно как реализовывать **paintEngine()**.

```
class Test :public QPaintDevice, public QWidget  {
public:
    //Метод от QPaintDevice, который требуется переопределить:

    QPaintEngine* paintEngine() const {
        //Что должно быть здесь?
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   Test test;
   QPainter painter(&test);
   painter.drawLine(100, 100, 200, 200);
   test.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

В результате выполнения этого кода, нужно что-бы на виджете test рисовалась линия из (100,100) в (200,200)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743669/4607234. В общем лучше задать некоторые параметры в классе, которые учитывать в `paintEvent()`, и если они меняются, вызвать `repaint()`.